# ANTLRWorks Debugger

Tags: antlr, antlr3, antlrworks, antlr2

I have a small code for which I want to see the AST in ANTLRWorks. In the preferences, I have chosen the compiler as 'com.sun.tools.javac' and the debugger is set as port '49100' and the time out is '20 seconds'.

The code is :

---

```
grammar try;
options {output=AST;}
tokens { MULT; } // imaginary token

poly: term ('+'^ term)*
;

term: INT ID  -> ^(MULT["*"] INT ID)
| INT exp -> ^(MULT["*"] INT exp)
| exp
| INT
| ID
;
exp : ID '^'^ INT
;

ID  : 'a'..'z'+ ;
INT : '0'..'9'+ ;
WS  : (' '|'\t'|'\r'|'\n')+ {skip();} ;
```

---

When i debug, I give the input text as '9a + 2b' and then it tries to connect and finally it gives the error 'Cannot launch the debuggerTab'.

I have disabled my antivirus and firewall as well. What could be the problem here?

Comment: It could be that the port is taken by some other process (or even a previous debug-session). FYI, using ANTLRWorks 1.4.3 and Orcale's JDK 1.7, the debugger produced this AST: http://oi41.tinypic.com/2lk5l4l.jpg

Comment: Thanks .. Can you kindly send me a picture of your compiler and debugger settings? .. I have chosen the compiler as 'com.sun.tools.javac' .. Initially i gave the path of my bin folder but it gives an error that file not found, and I tried to find javac file in the bin folder but couldnt find it

Comment: They're just the defaults, but here they are: http://i.imgur.com/jH6sv4q.png and http://i.imgur.com/RSZn2rs.png

Comment: Okay I am using the same ANTLRWorks and JDK .. but it doesn't work for me :( .. Its very irritating, I have tried everything to make it work !

Answer (score 0):

I think it occurred because you have not starting point in your program
you should write prog : in the initial of code